# How to find 95% confidence interval for the additive treatment effect in wilcoxon rank-sum test

Tags: r, statistics

Below is my data set:

```
    stereograms <- structure(list(Time = c(47.2, 22, 20.4, 19.7, 17.4, 14.7, 13.4, 
    13, 12.3, 12.2, 10.3, 9.7, 9.7, 9.5, 9.1, 8.9, 8.9, 8.4, 8.1, 
    7.9, 7.8, 6.9, 6.3, 6.1, 5.6, 4.7, 4.7, 4.3, 4.2, 3.9, 3.4, 3.1, 
    3.1, 2.7, 2.4, 2.3, 2.3, 2.1, 2.1, 2, 1.9, 1.7, 1.7, 19.7, 16.2, 
    15.9, 15.4, 9.7, 8.9, 8.6, 8.6, 7.4, 6.3, 6.1, 6, 6, 5.9, 4.9, 
    4.6, 3.8, 3.6, 3.5, 3.3, 3.3, 2.9, 2.8, 2.7, 2.4, 2.3, 2, 1.8, 
    1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2, 1.1, 1), condition = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -78L))
```

I have done the wilcoxon rank-sum test by the following code:

```
rawdatatest  <- wilcox.test(Time ~ condition, conf.int = TRUE, exact = TRUE, data = stereograms)

# Warning messages:
# 1: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(47.2, 22, 20.4, 19.7, 17.4, 14.7, 13.4,  :
#   cannot compute exact p-value with ties
# 2: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(47.2, 22, 20.4, 19.7, 17.4, 14.7, 13.4,  :
#   cannot compute exact confidence intervals with ties

rawdatatest

#   Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
#
# data:  Time by condition
# W = 973, p-value = 0.02706
# alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.1999475 4.2999223
# sample estimates:
# difference in location 
#               1.800068
```

Now how do I calculate the 95% confidence interval for the additive treatment effect for the above data set?

Comment: @MrFlick  How do I calculate the 95% confidence interval for the additive treatment effect?

Comment: The question isn't clear to me ... the output posted here shows a 95% CI of {0.1999475, 4.2999223}. Were you looking for something different from that?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that the Wilcoxon test result is the average treatment effect (ATE), such that

[image]

where N is the number of observed units, in order to get the additive treatment effect, all you need to do is multiply ATE by N.

In your example, `condition` is unbalanced, but let's assume that `condition = 2` is treated. Thus, the 95% c.i. for the additive treatment effect can be obtained by

```
N = length(stereograms$Time[stereograms$condition==2])
additive_treatment = rawdatatest$conf.int*N
```

Comment: Is this what you need? Let me know if I interpreted your question correctly.